# How to create an AttributeSyntax with a parameter

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to use Roslyn to create a parameter that looks something like this:

`[MyAttribute("some_param")]`

Now I can easily create the `AttributeSyntax` but can't figure out how to add an argument to the `ArgumentList` porperty using the `.AddArguments(ExpressionSyntax)` method. I'm just not sure what I need to do to create the appropriate expression.

Comment: https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/RoslynQuoter/issues/9

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm a fan of the `SyntaxFactory.Parse*` methods. (They're usually easier to understand)

You could use the following to generate the attribute you're looking for:

```
var name = SyntaxFactory.ParseName("MyAttribute");
var arguments = SyntaxFactory.ParseAttributeArgumentList("(\"some_param\")");
var attribute = SyntaxFactory.Attribute(name, arguments); //MyAttribute("some_param")

var attributeList = new SeparatedSyntaxList<AttributeSyntax>();
attributeList = attributeList.Add(attribute);
var list = SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(attributeList);   //[MyAttribute("some_param")]
```

Alternatively you could use hand-crafted approach from Kirill's RoslynQuoter tool. But I think the fact that no one wants to write that code without his tool is telling... ;)

The manual approach looks like:

```
var attributeArgument = SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(
    SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Token(default(SyntaxTriviaList), SyntaxKind.StringLiteralToken, "some_param", "some_param", default(SyntaxTriviaList))));

var otherList = new SeparatedSyntaxList<AttributeArgumentSyntax>();
otherList = otherList.Add(attributeArgument);
var argumentList = SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(otherList);
var attribute2 = SyntaxFactory.Attribute(name, argumentList);
```

In your example you want to add a `StringLiteralExpression` as your argument.